# Verb tense after the word tommorow

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

Would be grateful for any advice please.

I am attempting to write a novel (not for publication but for personal satisfaction only).

I am now running into grammar problems I have never even thought about before!
Here is the sentence that is causing my current confusion!

> "Tomorrow, when they made their vows in front of family and friends, both old and new, it would all be part of an ultimate grand design."

I am confused about the word "made" being correct or not. As "tomorrow" is in the future maybe it should be "make" ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: *Tomorrow when they make their....it will be part of....*   *Yesterday when they made their...it was part of....*

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TimeTravelTenseTrouble  The question is, where is the speaker relative to the events? Your narrator's point of view is able to time-travel, and can tell things from the point of view of another time-traveling narrator, if there is a purpose to it.

Comment: In other words, are you writing the story in the present tense - 'He walks down the road' - or the past tense - 'He walked down the road'? If the past, _made_ is fine.

Comment: What EllieK said, AND "*The next day, when they **made** their vows...it **would** be part of...*. This could be correct if the speaker is the narrator who knows what was going to happen.

Answer (score 1):

As @BobaFit said in a comment, "*The question is, where is the speaker relative to the events?*".

Context always matters, and to have an easy to read and understandable style, one must maintain a consistent point of view.

> As he sat in the waiting room, he thought about the significant events they had shared.
>
> He remembered how nervous they had felt on that plane flight, not because of any fear of flying, but because of *why* they were flying.
> Tomorrow, when they made their vows in front of family and friends, both old and new, it would all be part of an ultimate grand design.
>
> Then, at the wedding itself they had … .

That paragraph contains your sentence as you wrote it, and it fits well.
It shows *their* point of view as seen from *his* point of view.

But, in other contexts, from other points of view, it would be wrong and confusing.